# Javascript validator to set value of <input> list

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

I am new to JS and not able to use JS to populate numbers in an input tag.  I want the value >= 0.  This is my code.

```
<script id="EmployeeValue">
    for (int x = 0; x <= 100; x++) {
        int value = x;
    }
</script>
<h5>Number and Type of users affected</h5>
<input class="NumUsers" type="number" id="EmployeeValue" />
<input class="TypeUsers" type="text" />
```

Comment: 1. There are no `ìnt` in JavaScript. 2. Your loop will end with 100 in the input field if you do `for (var x = 0; x <= 100; x++) { document.getElementById("EmployeeValue").value = x; }`  you will not see the other values in the loop. 3. You would need to put that code uner the actual field since it has to exist first.  4. You cannot have duplicate IDs and and ID on a script tag rarely makes sense. What exactly are you hoping to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There are no `ìnt` in JavaScript.
2. Your loop will end with 100 in the input field if you do `for (var x = 0; x <= 100; x++) { document.getElementById("EmployeeValue").value = x; }`  you will not see the other values in the loop.
3. You would need to put that code under the actual field since it has to exist first.
4. You cannot have duplicate IDs and and ID on a script tag rarely makes sense.
5. To use the number input tag, read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number - to initially show 0, give it a value. To restrict values, use min/max:

What exactly are you hoping to achieve?

This will do something:

```html
<h5>Number and Type of users affected</h5>
<input class="NumUsers" type="number" id="EmployeeValue" 
placeholder="Max:100" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
<input class="TypeUsers" type="text" />

<script>
  // not sure you need this at all, but I will leave it in for now
  var value=0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    value = i;
  }
//    document.getElementById("EmployeeValue").value = value; // 100
  document.querySelector(".TypeUsers").value = value; // use querySelector to get by class
</script>
```

Comment: I used your code. The value started at 100 and was able to scroll to negative numbers.  How do I get the value to initially display 0 and not allow negative numbers?

Comment: Please see update. I commented out the setting of the value. There is no need for script if you just want to initialise the field

Comment: <h5>Number and Type of users affected</h5><input 
     class="NumUsers"type="number" id="EmployeeValue" /><input 
     class="TypeUsers"type="text" />
        <script>
            var x = 0, value = 0;
            for (x = 0; x <= 100; x++) {
                value = x;
            }
            document.getElementById("EmployeeValue").value = value; // 100
       </script>

Comment: What are you pasting?

Comment: That was updated code, I was not able to edit to make it look like a section of code.

Comment: Updated to do what? You are missing the min/max and still do not explain why you want to loop at all

Comment: @mplugjan I used a loop thinking that would be necessary to increment the value. Just saw the min/max value.

Comment: I am able to only see positive numbers.  How can the initial value not be 100?  Would removing the loop correct that?

Comment: The initial value can be whatever number (float/int) you want. Just change to `max="100" value="100" />`

Comment: I was able to make the placeholder 0 and that is better than it starting at 100.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: To see the placeholder, you need `value="" placeholder="0"` but that will not start the value at 0

Comment: If I want to use that value in back-end code, will I be able to do the way my code is currently written?

Comment: Sure. Your backend code should just be `<h5>Number and Type of users affected</h5>
<input class="NumUsers" type="number" id="EmployeeValue" 
placeholder="0" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
<input class="TypeUsers" type="text" />`

Comment: You WOULD of course need to CHECK the value on the backend too when the form is posted  - it is very easy to change the values using script or inspect before submitting

Comment: I am not sure if or how that value will be used, but that is a good information.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById("id")` to get an element with a specific id in the DOM.

Use `document.getElementsByClassName("class")` to get the elements with that class name in the DOM.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>  
  <h5>Number and Type of users affected</h5>
  <input class="NumUsers" type="number" id="EmployeeValue" />
  <input class="TypeUsers"type="text" />
  
  <script>    
    for (var x = 0; x <= 100; x++) {
      document.getElementById("EmployeeValue").value = x;
      document.getElementsByClassName("TypeUsers")[0].value = x;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

## To get started with JavaScript quickly:

- check out [**this YouTube video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEROU2XtPR8) about the basics
- run through the [**JavaScript 101**](https://hsablonniere.github.io/markleft/prezas/javascript-101.html) guide

---

*Good luck, have fun!*

Comment: I tried your code and initial value was zero and was able to see negative numbers.  How do I have the initial value to be invisible and not allow negative numbers?

Comment: Set the min, max, and value attributes on the specific element. Like this: `<input id="EmployeeValue"  type="number" min="0" max="100" value="" />`.